# SAP Java Connector: Is it possible to cut field values of extracted table?

Tags: java, saprfc, jco

I am extracting some SAP tables using the SAP Java Connector (via `RFC_READ_TABLE` or similar). Is it possible to pass some kind of maxlength for some fields of a table, e.g. if we have a field with size 3750 (like `PROFS` in table `USH04`) but I only want the first 100 characters - something like `LEFT(PROFS, 100)` in SQL?

Thank you for your helpful response!

Comment: I cannot answer this question. But, have you tried asking this question at the SAP forums ? If yes, how long ago did you post a question there ?

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev You want to imply that there is a website which offers better and faster answers to programming questions than Stackoverflow? **HERETIC!!!**

Comment: @Philipp - Yakshemash ! For "closed" technologies like SAP, possibly. For everything else, stack overflow is super fast. Maybe in the future it will have a brain sensor. You get answers before you can even post the question :) Chenqui.

Comment: This may not be directly solvable through the SQL code, but if using a library to execute code, [sap4j](http://sap4j.com) provides transformers that can be used to prune certain result column, as well as to enrich results if required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `RFC_READ_TABLE`, this is not possible. You may have to write your own function module to accomplish this. (Also be aware of [note 382318](http://service.sap.com/sap/support/notes/382318).)